# Magic numbers within voting test

Tags: voting, unit-tests

eosio.system_tests.cpp

```
BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE( vote_producers_in_and_out, eosio_system_tester ) try {
...
// give a chance for everyone to produce blocks
{
   produce_blocks(23 * 12 + 20);
...
```

What are these numbers?

Thank you!

Comment: 12 is the number of blocks each bp is scheduled to produce. not sure about the rest